# Django: Passing 'name' to Client.post()

Tags: python, django, forms, unit-testing, testing

I want to pass 'name' variable to request.POST.get() from Client in test in Django to be further processed by post function in view.

Something like that(product is ChoiceField in form):

```
response = c.post('/ordersys/orders/create/', {'product':product, 'amount':3}, name="Add")
```

I want that if to be True when posting from Client:

```
if request.POST.get("Add"):
   self.add_to_order(product, amount)
```

In form, submit like that works:

```
<input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add item to order">
```

Comment: Just pass it in the post parameter with some value of your choice eg: `{'product':product, 'amount':3, 'name': True}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Abdul Aziz Barkat in comment under my post i was able to make it work. I just had to add 'Add':True in my case.